# How do I re-sort a list of files grouped by directory?

Tags: windows, command-line, filesystems, sorting

From within a DOS batch file, how can I crudely re-sort a text file containing a manually maintained list of source files, so those files listed (from the same directory) in the small example extract below are grouped together again? I don't like how the DOS sort.exe reorders them in pure alphabetical order, where ctype.h and assert.h have been separated by files listed in the c++ sub-directory.

I'd prefer to do this using pure Windows XP/DOS (or Unix) commands - or if needed download an existing executable utility that doesn't need installing like tcl or perl scripts. It's a pity `dir /s /b` can't take input from file trying to use it as a format filter, not sure if ls can.

**To be reordered after DOS sort.exe has done its mischief:**

```
C:\NXP\LpcXpresso_3.6\Tools\arm-none-eabi\include\ar.h
C:\NXP\LpcXpresso_3.6\Tools\arm-none-eabi\include\argz.h
C:\NXP\LpcXpresso_3.6\Tools\arm-none-eabi\include\assert.h
C:\NXP\LpcXpresso_3.6\Tools\arm-none-eabi\include\c++\auto_ptr.h
C:\NXP\LpcXpresso_3.6\Tools\arm-none-eabi\include\c++\backward_warning.h
C:\NXP\LpcXpresso_3.6\Tools\arm-none-eabi\include\c++\binders.h
C:\NXP\LpcXpresso_3.6\Tools\arm-none-eabi\include\c++\boost_shared_ptr.h
C:\NXP\LpcXpresso_3.6\Tools\arm-none-eabi\include\c++\functional_hash.h
C:\NXP\LpcXpresso_3.6\Tools\arm-none-eabi\include\c++\hashtable_policy.h
C:\NXP\LpcXpresso_3.6\Tools\arm-none-eabi\include\cr_section_macros.h
C:\NXP\LpcXpresso_3.6\Tools\arm-none-eabi\include\ctype.h
C:\NXP\LpcXpresso_3.6\Tools\arm-none-eabi\include\dirent.h
C:\NXP\LpcXpresso_3.6\Tools\arm-none-eabi\include\envlock.h
C:\NXP\LpcXpresso_3.6\Tools\arm-none-eabi\include\envz.h
```

**Desired output:**

```
C:\NXP\LpcXpresso_3.6\Tools\arm-none-eabi\include\ar.h
C:\NXP\LpcXpresso_3.6\Tools\arm-none-eabi\include\argz.h
C:\NXP\LpcXpresso_3.6\Tools\arm-none-eabi\include\assert.h
C:\NXP\LpcXpresso_3.6\Tools\arm-none-eabi\include\cr_section_macros.h
C:\NXP\LpcXpresso_3.6\Tools\arm-none-eabi\include\ctype.h
C:\NXP\LpcXpresso_3.6\Tools\arm-none-eabi\include\dirent.h
C:\NXP\LpcXpresso_3.6\Tools\arm-none-eabi\include\envlock.h
C:\NXP\LpcXpresso_3.6\Tools\arm-none-eabi\include\envz.h
C:\NXP\LpcXpresso_3.6\Tools\arm-none-eabi\include\c++\auto_ptr.h
C:\NXP\LpcXpresso_3.6\Tools\arm-none-eabi\include\c++\backward_warning.h
C:\NXP\LpcXpresso_3.6\Tools\arm-none-eabi\include\c++\binders.h
C:\NXP\LpcXpresso_3.6\Tools\arm-none-eabi\include\c++\boost_shared_ptr.h
C:\NXP\LpcXpresso_3.6\Tools\arm-none-eabi\include\c++\functional_hash.h
C:\NXP\LpcXpresso_3.6\Tools\arm-none-eabi\include\c++\hashtable_policy.h
```

Comment: Windows XP does not use DOS. Do you mean `cmd` ("Command Prompt")?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is a very elegant solution but it does work:

1. Download the [GnuWin32 CoreUtils package](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/)
2. Extract the files somewhere accessible.
3. Use the 'sort' executable provided along the lines of:

   ```
   sort <input file> -t \ -k 9 -k 8 -k 7 -k 6 -k 5 -k 4 -k 3 -k 2 -k 1
   ```

This assumes a maximum depth in your files of 9 (9 fields separated in your paths by the back slash character). The output is:

```
C:\NXP\LpcXpresso_3.6\Tools\arm-none-eabi\include\ar.h
C:\NXP\LpcXpresso_3.6\Tools\arm-none-eabi\include\argz.h
C:\NXP\LpcXpresso_3.6\Tools\arm-none-eabi\include\assert.h
C:\NXP\LpcXpresso_3.6\Tools\arm-none-eabi\include\cr_section_macros.h
C:\NXP\LpcXpresso_3.6\Tools\arm-none-eabi\include\ctype.h
C:\NXP\LpcXpresso_3.6\Tools\arm-none-eabi\include\dirent.h
C:\NXP\LpcXpresso_3.6\Tools\arm-none-eabi\include\envlock.h
C:\NXP\LpcXpresso_3.6\Tools\arm-none-eabi\include\envz.h
C:\NXP\LpcXpresso_3.6\Tools\arm-none-eabi\include\c++\auto_ptr.h
C:\NXP\LpcXpresso_3.6\Tools\arm-none-eabi\include\c++\backward_warning.h
C:\NXP\LpcXpresso_3.6\Tools\arm-none-eabi\include\c++\binders.h
C:\NXP\LpcXpresso_3.6\Tools\arm-none-eabi\include\c++\boost_shared_ptr.h
C:\NXP\LpcXpresso_3.6\Tools\arm-none-eabi\include\c++\functional_hash.h
C:\NXP\LpcXpresso_3.6\Tools\arm-none-eabi\include\c++\hashtable_policy.h
```

If the paths were any longer than provided in your example you'd basically have to add further -k switches to ensure you keep your desired sorting.